# How to move from one intrinsic parameter to another?

Tags: image

Given the intrinsic parameters of 2 cameras, how do you move from one intrinsic parameter to another?

Comment: which intrinsic parameters do you mean? those in the camera projection matrix, or also distortion coefficients?

Answer (score 3):

let's say you have both camera matrices. I'll set up M1 as 640x480 with 60 degrees horizontal FoV and M2 as 1280x720 with 80 degrees. I'll use numpy and python for calculations.

```
>>> M1 = np.eye(3)
>>> M1[0:2,2] = (640-1)/2, (480-1)/2
>>> M1[0,0] = M1[1,1] = (640/2) / atan(60/2 * pi/180)
>>> M1
array([[663.42156,   0.     , 319.5    ],
       [  0.     , 663.42156, 239.5    ],
       [  0.     ,   0.     ,   1.     ]])

>>> M2 = np.eye(3)
>>> M2[0:2,2] = (1280-1)/2, (720-1)/2
>>> M2[0,0] = M2[1,1] = (1280/2) / atan(80/2 * pi/180)
>>> M2
array([[1050.09103,    0.     ,  639.5    ],
       [   0.     , 1050.09103,  359.5    ],
       [   0.     ,    0.     ,    1.     ]])
```

such a matrix maps a point from 3D onto the image plane. we can turn that equation around by multiplying with the inverted matrix. now you "project" that point on the image plane back into space (a vector/ray). it won't have a meaningful distance but the angle is correct.

[image: first step]

now you can multiply by the second camera matrix to "reproject" the point. group the matrices and multiply them into one. that will be the matrix you'll use.

[image: second step]

```
>>> M2 @ np.linalg.inv(M1)
array([[  1.58284,   0.     , 133.78221],
       [  0.     ,   1.58284, -19.59049],
       [  0.     ,   0.     ,   1.     ]])
```

it's not a full homography. it's not even a full affine transform. it only contains translation and scaling in the image plane. you can plug that into `cv::warpAffine` (chop off the third row so OpenCV will accept it).

Comment: Note that this solution is theoretically correct only for points at infinity. In practice, scene points close to the camera will not be warped correctly.

Comment: they will be if both cameras have the same optical center, which he specified in a now-deleted comment. a mere change in intrinsics does not depend on the distance of any scene points.

Comment: Except for the effect of sensor resolution :-)  

Take a picture of the wall of a building 1Km away with a wide angle lens. Warp it to emulate a telephoto picture: the building won't quite look as if it had been captured with a real telephoto, right?  That is why is wrote "theoretically" and "in practice".

Comment: I don't see your criticism. both points "at infinity" and "points close to the camera" will be mapped correctly, theoretically and practically. of course it's theoretically and practically impossible to extract fine details for a telephoto shot out of a panoramic one that has far lower angular resolution, but that wasn't your criticism in the first message. feel free to clarify what you wrote in the first comment. I don't believe it was that.

Comment: This helps to explain the true essence of a camera intrinsic matrix. Well done!

Comment: thanks for reminding me of this answer. there was a little off-by-one error in there. few would notice in practice but it's better to fix that.